# Using a .tpk file results in an app crash

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I'm attempting to use a .tpk file with Maximo Anywhere Work Execution on Android 6, but I'm experiencing an application crash when trying to access the Map view.

LogCat shows that the code recognises and processes the .tpk but then produces the error:

```
11-02 12:46:19.873: W/System.err(8251): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker
```

I've rebuilt the APK and updated Mobilefirst Studio to the latest IFIX version but this doesn't seem to help. Am I missing something?

Maximo Anywhere 7.6.1
Mobilefirst Studio 7.1.0.00-20171026-1607

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mobilefirst team have changed way to use gps in ifix from 2017. Basically they removed org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker. On Anywhere 762HF we have applied necessary fixes to support recent ifix. Suggestion is remove GeoBroker from config.xml file:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
```

You will find this config file into appName/android/native/res/xml folder.

Make sure that you have into this config.xml the new element used to provide gps feature, that is:

```
<feature name="WLGeolocationPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLGeolocationPlugin"/>
    </feature>
```

Let me know if this is enough to fix your problem.

Best Regards.

Comment: That stops the app crash but the location calls fail. I think the app may need to be recoded to use the new plugin. We have the 7.6.1 IFIX build 01157.001.866 but that doesn't seem to be utilising the new plugin.

Comment: Are you using mobilefirst plugin into eclipse and testing on real device? Make sure use plugin to deploy inside your device by using Run As command. Cordova is packaged into mobilefirst, so every time we apply a new MF ifix, we need double check every native feature. One of those changes you can double check is about your App.java file, i.e., WorkExecution.java. It is located into WorkExecution/android/native/src/com/WorkExecution. Make sure that it is extending CordovaActivity: public class WorkExecution extends CordovaActivity implements WLInitWebFrameworkListener {

Comment: Yes, the class is extending the deprecated WLDroidGap code. I guess the mobilefirst IFIX we're using finally removes the class. We have a PMR open with IBM so hopefully they can provide us with a code fix.

Comment: Just to add, the new plugin seems to expose the same interfaces as the coordinate capture now works. The additional problem was that our coordinates didn't match the coordinate system defined in the TPK file we were using.